# Dali JPT changes in eclipse 4.4

Tags: eclipse, dali

I have some eclipse plugins using old Dali JPT code( org.eclipse.jpt.core_2.2.1) running fine in eclipse 3.5 but I need to migrate them in eclipse 4.4. I can see there were significant changes in Dali JPT plugins, for example old org.eclipse.jpt.core.JptCorePlugin is completely removed.
For example if I want to use some of its static methods like JptCorePlugin.getJpaFile(..) how shall I do it in the new version( org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core_3.4.0 ).
I have no previous experience using it so any info,hints or directions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the JptCorePlugin behavior was moved to the appropriate model objects, namely JpaPlatform and JpaProject.  You can find documentation on these changes here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/New_Help_for_Old_Friends_VII#Dali

and additional information on how to use these object here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Dali_Developer_Documentation#Model

Instead of using the static methods on JptCorePlugin, you would instead do something like:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("Foo Project");
JpaProject jpaProject = (JpaProject) project.getAdapter(JpaProject.class);
jpaProject.getJpaFile(...);
```

Comment: One more thing concerning org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.context.PersistentAttribute , old interface methods getTypeMapping(), getPersistentType() are no more but now there are getDeclaringPersistentType(), getDeclaringTypeMapping(). Is it just that the naming is changed or they should be used in a different manner?

Comment: I think this was just a naming change.